# Numba not working

Tags: python, numba

Even after reinstalling `numba` and its dependencies, I always get :

> RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9

with this single line Python file :

```
import numba as nb
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: A basic question is what platform are you using and how are you installing numba and its dependencies? My general recommendation is to use conda if possible. My guess though is you have a mismatch between your numpy version and what the particular version of numba you're using expects

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, I finally made it working by following these steps:

1. Get llvmlite here : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#llvmlite  and install it with `pip install <file.whl>`, install the Windows 10 runtime if necessary
2. Update numpy with `pip uninstall numpy` and then install at least *numpy-1.10.4+vanilla-cp27-none*.
3. Get numba here : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numba and install it

Answer (score 0):

Even if the problem is already solved, I'd like to point a couple of details.

The error itself comes from NumPy. It is raised because numba has some support modules that depends NumPy's C API 'a', while your installed NumPy was '9'.

So the error was a NumPy version mismatch, solved by the update of the new version of NumPy.

And yes, all this is easier with conda as it will deal with the dependencies for you.